# WiX adding .net files to GAC

Tags: wix, gac, wix3.6

I have a problem copying assembly files to `GAC` using `msi installer file.` My project requires me to add some `.netmodule` files along with a `.dll` file to GAC. But using the `assembly = ".net"` for .netmodule file in the `<File>` element is throwing an error(build error).

```
Error   2   The assembly file 
'C:\Users\p486\Desktop\DCUBEII\GAC\Cdcube_inq_dynftrm_lnk_srv.netmodule' appears to be
invalid.  <br/>Please ensure this is a valid assembly file and that the user has the 
appropriate access rights to this file. <br/> More information: HRESULT:<br/> 
0x80131018  C:\Wix\MainProject\MainProject\GACFiles.wxs 16  1   MainProject
```

How can is copy those .netmodule files to GAC?

If we manually drag and drop the .dll file into C:\Windows\assembly folder, all the .netmodule files are being copied automatically but if try to copy only the .dll file into GAC using installer, its throwing an installtime error. How to copy those files to GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not played with `.netmodule` files much but my understanding is that the `.netmodule` needs to be in the same `Component` as the `assembly`.  For example:

```
<Component>
   <File Assembly='.net' Source='path\to\assembly.dll' />
   <File Source='path\to\first.netmodule' />
   <File Source='path\to\second.netmodule' />
   ...
</Component>
```

The `Component` will GAC the assembly and carry all the `.netmodule` files along with it.

Comment: I have atleast 100 .netmodule files. Can we harvest all those <file> elements in a single component using heat.exe?